# Laravel close page instead of return

Tags: laravel, redirect, html

I have view with form and on button click submit (all data goes to DB) I want to make instead of *return redirect* **close** it. Any ideas best way to do it? Last line of function:

```
        return redirect('/review');
```

Comment: Put your code here

Comment: What do you mean by 'close it'? Close the browser tab? That's not possible with PHP, it has to be done via JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible using PHP ! Even with Javascript you can only close windows/tabs that you previously opened yourself `window.open` and `window.close`.